# ExtJS Form within a CardLayout

Tags: extjs, extjs3

Whenever I add a form to a card layout, all the form items seem to disappear. I tested my layout here:
http://tof2k.com/ext/formbuilder/
with this code and got the same result, (use show/edit JSON to try it or build one yourself)
How can I make the for fields visible?

```
{
xtype:"panel",
title:"Panel",
items:[{
    layout:"card",
    title:"CardLayout Container",
    activeItem:"0",
    items:[{
        xtype:"form",
        title:"Form",
        items:[{
            xtype:"textfield",
            fieldLabel:"Text",
            name:"textvalue"
          },{
            xtype:"textfield",
            fieldLabel:"Text",
            name:"textvalue"
          }]
      }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer, ensure you set the `height` property of the form or else it will be hidden.